# Pass sub domain cookie to main domain

Tags: php, cookies, forum, vbulletin

I use vbulletin forum in address : forum.name.com

How pass forum cookie to main domain ? ( name.com )

I use this code on Local and worked full , But this code not work on Server !

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["bbuserid"])){
echo 'Please Login';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you try?

Do you even control vBulletin's cookie creation, I believe it is automated?

Because from subdomain to main domain, all that is "required" is the path/domain modification of the cookie, i.e. make it create under the domain of name.com rather than forum.name.com see https://www.php.net/setcookie path and domain parameters

Good luck

Comment: after login to vbulletin (forum.name.com), cookie ($_COOKIE["bbuserid"]) not work on name.com . bbuserid create by forum.name.com

Comment: Yes, right, it doesn't work, because vBulletin creates the cookie with the domain context of forum.name.com. You can create a custom vBulletin domain which will be shown to users "leaving" your forum, and have that page set the cookie to a wider domain scope than forum.site.com

Comment: I don't have access to vBulletin but people say "Admin CP -> vBulletin Options -> Cookies and HTTP Header Options" is the place to modify http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/forum/vbulletin-legacy-versions-products/legacy-vbulletin-versions/vbulletin-3-0-how-do-i-and-troubleshooting-forum/125955-how-set-right-cookie-path-and-cookie-domain